# php.ini session memcache handler

Tags: php, session, memcached

i read much about set session handler to store session data in memcached server, but always is wrote something like this open php.ini and set:

session.save_path = "tcp :/ / m1: 11211, tcp :/ / m2: 11211"

what will happen when i would store session data using session_set_save_handler function

```
class MemcachedSessionHandler
{
   private $memcached;

   function __construct(){
      $this->memcached = new Memcached();
      $this->memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1','11211');
   }

   function open($savePath, $sessionName)
   {
      // here i open session
   }

   function close()
   {
      // here i close session
   }

   function read($id)
   {
      // here i read data from memcached
      return $this->memcached->get($id);
   }

   function write($id, $data)
   {
      // here i write
      return $this->memcached->set($id, $data);
   }

   function destroy($id)
   {
       return $this->memcached->destroy($id, $data);
   }

   function gc($maxlifetime)
   {
   }
}

$handler = new MemcachedSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler(
   array($handler, 'open'),
   array($handler, 'close'),
   array($handler, 'read'),
   array($handler, 'write'),
   array($handler, 'destroy'),
   array($handler, 'gc')
 );
```

It is not better idea to implement this function to serve php session using memcached instead fumble in php.ini? Meaby here is some bad things wich i dont know ;( Can someone write opinio about it?